# Styling GeoJSON with a styleFunction

Tags: openlayers

I've problems symbolizing the result of a GeoJSON. I do the function and define the intervals based on the results of the GeoJSON. I want to symbolize the abundance field.
I put a part of the GeoJSON, example:

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-9,43.5],[-9,44],[-8,44],[-8,43.5],[-9,43.5]]]]},"properties":{"id":"3446","aphia_id_code":"140600","camp":"N13","abundance":"39.898","geojson":"{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[-9,43.5],[-9,44],[-8,44],[-8,43.5],[-9,43.5]]]]}"},"id":18},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-5,43.5],[-5,44],[-4,44],[-4,43.5],[-5,43.5]]]]},"properties":{"id":"3838","aphia_id_code":"140600","camp":"N13","abundance":"2.205","geojson":"{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[-5,43.5],[-5,44],[-4,44],[-4,43.5],[-5,43.5]]]]}"},"id":19}
```

And this is the styling function

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#425364', width: 1}),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill()
});

var dist = function(feature) {
    var value = feature.get('abundance');
    var color = value <  100 ? '#F6CECE' :
                value <  1.500 ? '#F5A9A9' :
                value <  12.000 ? '#F78181' :
                value <  22.000 ? '#FA5858' :
                value < 43.000 ? '#FE2E2E' : '#ff0000';
    style.getFill().setColor(color);
    return style;
};
```

When I represent it, it does not respect the color code, it sets the same color for all intervals. I think if this can be caused by formatting numbers, but I'm not really sure.  How can I represent these intervals with those values?

Comment: As it is written, it should return a color for values `< 100` and one for `>=100`. You may want to order the conditions from the smallest to the largest value.

Comment: Are those points in numbers meant as decimal points or thousands delimiters? I suspect they are supposed to be thousands delimiters, so just leave them out. If they are indeed decimal points, then see comment from @JGH.

Comment: Those points in numbers are decimal points.  var color = value <  100 ? '#F6CECE' : value >=100 ? '#F6CECE' : value < 1.500  ? '#F5A9A9' : value >= 1.500 ? '#F78181' : ... so?  why rounding in the DB or in the PHP query wouldn't be correct, right?

Comment: If those are indeed meant as decimal points, then it should be: `var color = value <  1.500 ? '#F5A9A9' : value <  12.000 ? '#F78181' : value <  22.000 ? '#FA5858' : value < 43.000 ?  '#FE2E2E' : value <  100 ? '#F6CECE' : '#ff0000'`. But this is not really a GIS related question, so it's more suitable StackOverflow site.

Comment: I already understood how this classification works. But maybe it will not be the best way for me, maybe I will have to do it by quantiles, but it would change the classification system, right? it should be like classes or something like that. Maybe I should ask another question.

Comment: Then this is not GIS related question, but more JS related one, and as such more suitable for StackOwerflow site.